# Why does a single INSERT in a procedure not qualify for an explicit transaction?

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation where I want to implement a single `INSERT` in a stored procedure to make sure that I have a locking mechanism in the form of a transaction.

This [article](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) says

> If your procedure does not perform any updates or only has a single
>   INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/MERGE statement, you typically don't have an
>   explicit transaction at all.

Does this mean the stored procedure is of no use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because if there's only a single `INSERT` statement, that will run in an *implicit* transaction in SQL Server anyway.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what it says. There is a keyword *typically*. When you do a single `INSERT` statement, the operation is automatically atomic. Even if you're inserting 1000 rows, they either all insert, or none insert. In a sense, there is an *implicit* transaction there. The word *typically* is important because, while this implicit transaction is atomic, you can't roll it back yourself. For example, maybe you're doing something like (contrived example):

```
INSERT INTO MyLog (Record)
SELECT Record FROM OldLog

If (@@ROWCOUNT < 500)
    ROLLBACK
```

Well you couldn't do that `ROLLBACK` because there is no *explicit* transaction. If you wrap it in a `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, now you could.

In general though, you use explicit transactions when you have multiple statements you want to be atomic. For example, you're inserting into 3 different tables and you need them all to succeed or all fail. By having an explicit transaction you can `ROLLBACK` so you never end up in a state where Table1 is updated but Table2 and Table3 are not.

So I agree with the statement, *typically* you don't need an explicit transaction when you have a single `INSERT`, but there might be weird situations where you need one.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a transaction for your insert, SQL will assume you don't want one and will release locks after the proc ends.

So just use an explicit transaction to be sure, e.g.:

```
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT ...
COMMIT TRAN
```

Or, using the same connection, start a transaction explicitly, call your proc, then commit your transaction explicitly before closing your connection.